# Why can't we look up the type of an object pointed at at compile-time?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am trying to understand virtual functions in C++.

```
struct B {
  int f() { return 1;}
}

struct D : B {
  int f() { return 1;}
}
```

In the main function:

```
B* b = new D;
b.f()
```

My understanding is that there is a "competition" between the base class and the derived class: they both have a function with the same name and the same signature. When `b.f()` is called, only one of them will be chosen. In the virtual case:

- the winner is chosen based on the type of the object pointed at by b
- that choice is made at run-time

In the non-virtual case:

- the winner is chosen based on the type of the pointer b
- that choice is made at compile-time

I don't understand the causal relationships between

1. the use of the `virtual` keyword
2. the ability to lookup the type of the object pointed at by b
3. compile time vs run time

Why can't we do (2) at compile-time for example?

Comment: Because of the aliasing problem. In C++, it may be hard to impossible to guess the type of an object pointed to by a base class pointer. That's why virtual calls are typically implemented using a virtual table for method lookup instead of relying on the type of object pointed to.

Comment: @arne: That is not the aliasing problem. The aliasing problem is that you're given two pointers, which may or may not point to the same object, and you have to determine whether a write to one would require re-reading the other.

Comment: @MSalters Sorry, you're correct. I mixed up the terms.

Comment: In this case, the compiler may decide to lookup at compile time, because it knows for sure that `b` will be a `D`. This optimisation is allowed. But that's not the general case, as the answers below show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do (2), provided you do (1), use `virtual`. You do (2) with `typeid`. It's not the most performant method, in general. (A feedback effect: it's rarely useful, so rarely optimized, which makes it even less used, etc).

The reason for the dependency is that `virtual` enables RTTI (Run Time Type Information), which is also needed for 2. One common form of RTTI is the so-called `vtable`, which is a table that holds pointers to the virtual functions of a given class. Each object with virtual functions has a pointer to this table. The `typeid` information can be added to such a table in a few ways (embed, data pointer, pointer to function returning it, etc). But there are also other options to implement RTTI besides a pointer to a`vtable`, so don't assume it's the only way.

You also wonder why you can't do this at runtime. Consider the following bit of code

```
void Foo(std::ostream&);
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  if (argc == 2)
  {
    std::ofstream outFile(argv[1]);
    Foo(outFile);
  }
  else
  {
     Foo(std::cout);
  }
}
```

Clearly, when compiling `Foo` you have no idea what you'll get at runtime. That depends on the command line. At compile time, you just know you'll get an `ostream&`.

Answer (score 1):

There are often cases where you can't know the type at compile time. For example, consider a game where you have some physical objects (entities) and each might behave different on contact. E.g.

```
struct Entity {
   int x,y,w,h;
   virtual void onPlayerContact() {}
};

struct ExitDoor : Entity {
   void onPlayerContact() { exitLevel(); }
};

struct Monster : Entity {
   void onPlayerContact() { diePlayer(); }
};

//...
```

Now you keep all existing entities in a big list and in every frame, you go through the list, check if your player has contact with the entity and if so, you call the `onPlayerContact`. I.e.:

```
static std::set<Entity*> entities;
static Player* player;

void frame() {
   for(Entity* entity : entities) {
      if(player->contacts(entity))
         entity->onPlayerContact(); // it's only known at runtime what to call here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example

```
void some_function(B* b)
{
    b.f();
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    cin >> i;

    if (i == 0)
    {
         B *b = new B();
         some_function(b);
    }
    else
    {
         D *d = new D();
         some_function(d);
    }

     return 0;
}
```

In compile time, you don't know the exact type of the object passed to the function **"some_function(B* b)"**. It should be decided at run-time.